# Inner while loop never completes

Tags: java

How can I keep my inner while loop from running infinitely? The thing is that without the outer while loop, the inner loop will run with no problem. I know that it has to do something with the outer loop, but I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Tester
{
    static LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    static LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    private static void stringMethod()
    {
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
        Random random = new Random();
        String flashCard ="";

        int rand;

        while (!list2.isEmpty()) {
            if (list2.size() != 1) {
                flashCard = list2.remove(random.nextInt(list2.size() - 1));
            } else {
                flashCard = list2.remove(0);
            }

            stringSet.add(flashCard);

            while (stringSet.size() != 4) {
                rand = random.nextInt(list1.size());
                stringSet.add(list1.get(rand));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            list1.add("String " + i);
        }

        list2.addAll(list1);
        stringMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you step it through the code?

Comment: For problems like these where you need to remove items from a `list`, use an `iterator`. Removing it like how you are doing it causes problems

Comment: @Rakesh why use an iterator over a list?

Comment: @Rakesh you can't use iterator here, by using iterator you can only delete the current element. OP is trying to delete a random element.

Comment: Not "iterator over list", use an iterator to go through the list. Use `list2.iterator()` to get the iterator object, and then use `hasNext()` and `next()` to get the items that you need

Comment: @karthik Fair point, this is a tough nut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your while loop condition

```
       while (stringSet.size() != 4)
```

Once your stringSet size is 4 you will break this loop but next time it goes in to infinite loop, because you are adding element to `stringSet` before inner while loop and it's size becomes 5 and it will never break.

You might want to use

```
                  while (stringSet.size() <= 4)
```

this will stop you going into infinite loop but I am sure this what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the inner loop will never terminate once the size of the Set reaches 5. `list1` has 5 elements, so eventually all of them will be added to `stringSet`. It's hard to see what you are trying to do here, so I can't suggest how to fix it.

Changing

```
while (stringSet.size() != 4)
```

to

```
while (stringSet.size() < 4)
```

will prevent the infinite loop, but I'm not sure if that's the desired logic.